# Difference between db.String(6) and db.String(length=6) in python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am reading a friends code and I don't understand why sometimes he uses the following:

```
aFieldInATable = db.Column(db.String(6), nullable=False)
```

and other times he uses:

```
anotherField = db.Column(db.String(length=255), nullable=False)
```

What is the difference between `db.String(6)` and `db.String(length=6)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One uses a positional parameter, the other a keyword parameter.

If the `String()` object definition has `length` as the first parameter, the two versions *mean the same thing* as Python will fill parameters from left to right, even if those paramaters are keyword parameters.

Presumably, you are looking at code using SQLAlchemy; the [`String()` type](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/types.html#sqlalchemy.types.String) has exactly that signature; `length` is the first parameter:

> ```
> class sqlalchemy.types.String(length=None, collation=None, convert_unicode=False, unicode_error=None, _warn_on_bytestring=False)
> ```

Comment: So if they're the same, can you think of any reason why he would alternate between the two?

Comment: @RockJake28: Bad short-term memory?

Comment: @RockJake28: There is no reason to use one over the other, really. Perhaps the keyword-using version can be seen as self-documenting.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Fair enough. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what it looks like - [a SQLAlchemy definition of a string type column](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/types.html?highlight=string#sqlalchemy.types.String) - then the only difference explicitness. Some people say it's unnecessary verbosity but it is a nice reminder of what your parameter means when you're learning, refactoring a lot or have a long list of parameters.

You can read more on keyword arguments here

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/style.html#function-arguments